# Specify additional port bindings to Docker Compose on the command line

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I start a container using `docker compose`, is it possible to specify additional ports to forward on the command line, beyond those already specified in the YAML file? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the ports set in *docker-compose*. Remember that Docker commands are independent, but docker compose is a tool that helps you use most of them at once.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).